# Why does the output of the neural network is the same for all samples

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm using Pytorch to make a regression model (neural network). Just train and test it on the same sample (because i'm just learning how to build a neural network).

The data is the fish market dataset from kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/aungpyaeap/fish-market

Small sample from the training Tensor:

```
tensor([[ 0.0000, 23.2000, 25.4000, 30.0000, 11.5200,  4.0200],
        [ 0.0000, 24.0000, 26.3000, 31.2000, 12.4800,  4.3056],
        [ 0.0000, 23.9000, 26.5000, 31.1000, 12.3778,  4.6961],
        [ 0.0000, 26.3000, 29.0000, 33.5000, 12.7300,  4.4555],
        [ 0.0000, 26.5000, 29.0000, 34.0000, 12.4440,  5.1340],
        [ 0.0000, 26.8000, 29.7000, 34.7000, 13.6024,  4.9274],
        [ 0.0000, 26.8000, 29.7000, 34.5000, 14.1795,  5.2785],
        [ 0.0000, 27.6000, 30.0000, 35.0000, 12.6700,  4.6900],
        [ 0.0000, 27.6000, 30.0000, 35.1000, 14.0049,  4.8438],
        [ 0.0000, 28.5000, 30.7000, 36.2000, 14.2266,  4.9594],
        [ 0.0000, 28.4000, 31.0000, 36.2000, 14.2628,  5.1042],
        [ 0.0000, 28.7000, 31.0000, 36.2000, 14.3714,  4.8146],
        [ 0.0000, 29.1000, 31.5000, 36.4000, 13.7592,  4.3680],
```

Small Sample from the target tensor:

```
tensor([[ 242.0000],
        [ 290.0000],
        [ 340.0000],
        [ 363.0000],
        [ 430.0000],
        [ 450.0000],
        [ 500.0000],
        [ 390.0000],
        [ 450.0000],
        [ 500.0000],
        [ 475.0000],
        [ 500.0000],
        [ 500.0000],
        [ 340.0000],
        [ 600.0000],
        [ 600.0000],
        [ 700.0000],
        [ 700.0000],
```

The neural network:

```
class NeuralNetFish(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(6, 10)
        self.tanh1 = nn.Tanh()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.tanh2 = nn.Tanh()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc1(x)
        out = self.tanh1(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        out = self.tanh2(out)
        out = self.fc3(out)
        return out


model = NeuralNetFish()
criteron = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.02)

for i in range(10000):
    output = model(fish_tensor)
    loss = criteron(output, weight_tensor)
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print("Epoch:", i, " ---  Loss:", loss.item())
```

OUTPUT:

```
Epoch: 0  ---  Loss: 286071.78125
Epoch: 1000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
Epoch: 2000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
Epoch: 3000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
Epoch: 4000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
Epoch: 5000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
Epoch: 6000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
Epoch: 7000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
Epoch: 8000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
Epoch: 9000  ---  Loss: 127342.515625
```

And i get the same output for all the samples.

Comment: You perform the `epochs` loop but you do not traverse batches of the training data, why is that?

Comment: @DavidS Is it gonna be a problem just to perform Gradient Descent instead of mini batch GD?

Comment: Not really, but you might get stuck in a local minimum that way.

Comment: Okay i'm gonna try to divide it into batches and try

Comment: @DavidS It didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale your inputs.

Your inputs are roughly in range `[0, 40]`, you take linear combinations of these numbers, and then apply the `tanh` function. Most likely your outputs will be at the "saturated" region of the `tanh` thus the gradients are roughly zero. Your neurons are [dead](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks).

To overcome this issue:

1. Scale your inputs: compute the mean and std over the training set (mean and std are 6-vectors in your case). Subtract the mean and divide by the std to have your inputs distributed roughly as `N(0, 1)`.
2. Replace the `tanh` activations with [`nn.PReLU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.PReLU.html).
3. You should tune your learning-rate to be in accordance with the batch size (in your case batch size = entire dataset).